# How will you debug a webpage which is not loading?

Tags: html, debugging, jsp

**A web page is not loading/hanging. How will you debug it?**

I have been asked this question couple of times during my telephonic interviews. But I don't know the perfect answer.

I had given answers such as checking if the web-app is deployed properly, the internet itself might be slow, the JSP might have some errors, checking logs for any such detail, etc. But interviewer kept asking "These are all good checks, but what if all of these are fine, what else might be wrong?"

Also, it is not a JavaScript specific question. I can debug the JS/jQuery code using `debugger`, or following the `console.log()`. But how will you debug a plain JSP page?

Can any web-application gurus at SO help?

Comment: I read "hanging/not responding" quite differently than "not loading"...I'd look into debugging from the client end (browser)?

Comment: @lc.: corrected the question. Thanks.

Comment: you check the server error-log file?

Comment: @Ibu: Yes, i had given that answer (mentioned in the question), but the interviwer was expecting something further

Comment: ping the servers IP, make sure the server itself is actually responding

Comment: It can be that the interview question had no correct solution, they just tried to get you to list as many error sources as possible.

Comment: @biziclop: yup, now even i think the same.

Answer (score 2):

Once you know that you can't simply get to your site in the expected way (what I call the [Hail Mary Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass)), then you need to start from the inside out.

Because of the multiple failure points a website can have, I always create a command line environment that allows me to test the framework & DB operation independently of the web server, firewall settings, etc. This can take some fiddling depending on what you are using, but I've done this successfully with Django, WordPress, Drupal, etc.

Once I know the app itself is working, I connect with a command line client (e.g. `links`) to see if a client coming from `localhost` works as expected. This confirms that the server itself is working (at least partially). Then I test from another host on the *same LAN.* More than once I've seen `localhost` work and LAN access not work, and the problem is almost always server configuration or firewall configuration.

If all of that works, but you still can't get to your site from the internet, then it is a networking / firewall setting somewhere further up the food chain. Try to find a host that is one step farther up from where you last succeeded and test that. Lather, rinse, repeat.